# kubectl apply -f *.yml "The connection to the server xxxx:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?"

Tags: kubernetes

kubectl apply -f *.yml
The connection to the server xxxx:6443 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

Allowed port 6443 in FW settings
Restart kubelet

#kubectl config view

apiVersion: v1
clusters:

- cluster:
  certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
  server: https://192.168.1.103:6443
  name: kubernetes
  contexts:
- context:
  cluster: kubernetes
  user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
  current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
  kind: Config
  preferences: {}
  users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
  client-certificate-data: DATA+OMITTED
  client-key-data: DATA+OMITTED

Comment: Share your kubernetes configuration